# Relative topology Moore plane

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I would like to know how to evaluate the relative topology (If $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space and $A\subseteq X$, then $\tau_A:=\{G\cap A|  G\in \tau\}$ is the relative topology) from the following three subsets

(1) $A:=\{(0,y)|y>0\}=\{0\}\times (0,\infty)\subseteq \Gamma$ where $\Gamma:=\{(x,y\in\mathbb R^2 | y\ge 0)\}$ is the [Moore plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane)

(2)$B:=\{(x,y)|y>0\}$

(3) $C=\{(x,0)|x\in\mathbb R\}$

In (1) I would say $\{G\cap A| G\in \tau\}=\{G|G\in\tau\}$

In (2) $B$ itself

In (3) $\{0\}$

How can this things be proven in a formal way, not intuitively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some HINTS:

(1) Every non-empty $G\in\tau$ contains an ordinary Euclidean open ball in the plane, so if $\varnothing\ne G\in\tau$, it’s **never** true that $G\cap A\in\tau$. Try to show that every basic open set in $\Gamma$ intersects $A$ in a set of the form $\{0\}\times(a,b)$, where $0\le a<b$, or of the form $\{0\}\times[0,a)$, where $a>0$. (The base for $\tau$ that I have in mind is the one described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane).) Then compare this with the topology that $A$ inherits from the usual Euclidean topology of $\Bbb R^2$.

(2) $B$ is not a family of open sets, so it can’t possibly be $\tau_B$. Try to show that $\tau_B$ is the ordinary Euclidean topology on $B$.

(3) $C$ is the $x$-axis; it’s true that $\{0\}\in\tau_C$, but there are many, many other relative open sets in $C$. Is $\{2\}\in\tau_C$? What about $\{-\pi\}$?

Comment: (1) Do you really mean basic open sets in $X$ ? I think you mean open sets in $\Gamma$ right?. If $G$ is an open set in $\Gamma$, then $G\cap A=\{0\}\times (a,b)$ or $G\cap A=\{0\}\times [0,a)$, this is clear to me, the comparison with the Euclidean topology not, I guess you mean that it satifies the conditions for an Euclidean topology?

Comment: @Babla: (1) Yes: I didn’t notice that you’d switched from the original $X$ to $\Gamma$. (2) I mean that if $\tau'$ is the Euclidean topology on the plane, then $\tau_A=\tau'_A$.

Comment: And for this is it necessary to show that $\tau_A$ satifies the three conditions for an euclidean topology http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_topology ?

Comment: @Babla: Why work so hard? Start with the base of open balls for $\tau'$ and observe that these balls have exactly the same intersections with $A$ as the members of the natural base for $\tau$.

Comment: Thank you, two more questions. How does $\tau_B$ look explcitly? In (3) since $C$ is the x axis, I guess there is no reason why 2 and -pi should not be elements in $\tau_C$, so $\tau_C$ is the set of all elmeents on the $x$ axis?

Comment: @Babla: Members of $\tau_C$ are **sets** of points, so $2$ cannot be an element of $\tau_C$: the set $\{2\}$, on the other hand, is an element of $\tau_C$. It really is important to distinguish between $x$ and $\{x\}$. Yes, $\{\langle x,0\rangle\}\in\tau_C$ for each $x\in\Bbb R$, but that means that every union of such singletons is also in $\tau_C$: topologies are by definition closed under taking unions. (I slipped up when I wrote $\{0\}\in\tau_C$: that should have been $\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}\in\tau_C$.) This means that the topology $\tau_C$ is a familiar one, with a name of its own; ...

Comment: ... what is it? As for $\tau_B$, what does the Euclidean topology on $B$ look like? They’re the same thing.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally clicked on "discussion to chat". Ok for $\tau_B$ we simply have the unions of the open intervals $(x,y)$. The thing with $\tau_C$ is now clear to me, but I do not know whats the name of this special type of topology?

Comment: @Babla: $B$ is the whole open upper half-plane: its open sets are definitely not intervals! Are you thinking of $A$? $\tau_C$ is the *discrete topology* on $\Bbb R\times\{0\}$.